# How to rank mysql with groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

Guy I am trying to ranking some data from my database, and I notice that it's going very wrong when I put the group by clause;

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS RankSemGenero
    ,a.nome AS Artista
    ,f.nome AS Musica
    ,SUM(rnk.total) AS Tocadas
    ,rnk.mes AS Mes
    ,rnk.dia AS Dia
    ,current_timestamp() AS Criado_Em_Sem_Genero
    ,23 AS RankComGenero
    ,current_timestamp() AS Criado_Em_Com_Genero
    /*,CASE rnk.categoria
        WHEN 1 then 'AM'
        WHEN 2 then 'FM'
        WHEN 3 then 'Web'
        WHEN 4 then 'Comunitaria'
    END AS Categoria_Radio*/
    ,'Todas' AS TipoEmissora
    ,5 AS Relevancia_Emissora
    ,'Nacional' AS Local
    ,5 AS Relevancia_Local
    ,1 AS fl_ativo
FROM rnk201901 rnk
LEFT JOIN artistas a ON rnk.artista = a.id
LEFT JOIN fonogramas f ON rnk.fonograma = f.id
WHERE rnk.dia = 10
-- AND rnk.fonograma = 35876
-- GROUP BY rnk.fonograma
ORDER BY rnk.total DESC;
```

This code above bringing the information on the right way 1 until ....

But if I change the GROUP BY line, I am receiving something like: 1700 instead of 1.

```
GROUP BY rnk.fonograma
```

Any idea how to handle this group by counting 1 by 1?

Thanks!!

Comment: What determinate the rank order?

Comment: this field SUM(rnk.total)

Comment: can you share some sample data and expected output? If you add the group buy but remove the @rank do you get the expected result?

Comment: sure, https://pastebin.com/UyCTbuZN this has two example, the first one is what is going wrong, but how I need (With GROUP BY) the second is the right, but wrong way without GROUP BY clause.

Comment: In the second one you put random values? because the Tocadas values are different for same people. Again if you remove @rank but add group by you get the expected result or not?

Comment: The first one is just ORDER BY ` rnk.total ` the second one I have the GROUP BY and the ` ORDER BY SUM(rnk.total) ` because when I do the GROUP, I need to concatenate the ORDER clause too.

Comment: So the group by give you the expected result or not? if you have the right result only have to focus on the rank. otherwise need to fix the group by first

Comment: no, it's not, That what I have NO IDEA how to handle that haha, https://pastebin.com/jm9cscj1 this one is the query that "works", this one that doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/ABAYwHP4

Comment: what mean doesnt work? If I dont have the sample data and the tables I cant test it. And again I ask if the query without rank work. And I still see the rank there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery, when using variables with `group by`:

```
select (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank, t.*
from (<your aggregation query here with order by>) t cross join
     (select @rank := 0) params;
```

Comment: shouldnt the order by be outside? or doesnt matter?

Comment: Also probably want sort by `SUM(rnk.total) AS Tocadas`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Technically yes.  But the code only works because MySQL materializes the subquery as a sorted table.

Comment: Definitively I don't know how to do that, can you help me with that?